# New licence to upgrade from VS 2017 to 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have a monthly licence for VS 2017 Professional. I can't find anywhere that mentions if I need a new licence if I install VS 2019 Professional.

Can I install it, and transfer/use my 2017 licence on 2019?

thanks, Mark

Comment: Maybe ask Microsoft support for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Microsoft subscription is not limit you to specific version. All MS IDEs are available for download and install. So you could install VS2019.
On [this](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing) page you can see

> Visual Studio Professional IDE for individuals and small teams for PC and Mac

There is no version.

And of course you can every time download, install and enter your credentials. And if your license is incompatible with installed version you will be informed :)